# Running nagios on nginx

Tags: nginx, nagios

I'm trying to set up Nagios on Nginx and I'm having trouble. I used  [this](http://wiki.linuxwall.info/doku.php/en:ressources:dossiers:supervision:nagios3) as a guide, but I still can't access Nagios from the web.

Just to confirm, I have nagios, fcgiwrap and php-cgi running. When i go to example.com/nagios, it brings up the nagios pages. But when i click on anything substantial, i get a message saying "Error: Could not read host and service status information!". I am sure it has something to do with permissions, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Anyone know what i can do?

thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks. meanwhile i found the answer

Answer (score 1):

Found out my problem. It had to do with file permissions for the nagios files. Nginx ran under a different user, so it didn't have the right permissions to access the nagios files.